# what is specific requirenment for harvest plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, harvest-scm

Please keep in mind these terms

**Harvest server** : The Repo server used to manage the code repository.

**Harvest client** :(Harvest SCM) The end user use to take code checkout and checkin from Harvest server.

**Harvest client plugin** : (CA SCM PLUGIN)A eclipse plugin that provides all functionality of **Harvest client** in eclipse.

I am using Harvest client[Workbench] **version 12.5 X64 bit**.Server is also 12.5.

I want to install a eclipse plugin compatible of harvest client version 12.5, so that i can checkin and checkout repositary code to and from my system. Currently , I am using an old version of eclipse "Juno" with harvest plugin of 12.1 version , and my server is Migrated(Repo server of Harvest) from 12.1 to 12.5 server version , and due to that , some of functionality of harvest plugin is not working with updated version of 12.5(Harvest Server and Harvest client)

**So please suggest me which newer version of Eclipse is fully compatible with Harvest client plugin 12.5.**

I have tried eclipe version of kepler(64bit)JRE(64 bit) with Harvest SCM plugin 12.5 , and it worked fine,But now i am not able to use that same eclipse , as it reporting always , that Please install all required plugins for Harvest plugin to work , and that is very strange , as it is the same i was using (with same JRE backup) before i format my system(Windows 7 64 bit version).
So i tried by again downloading the eclipse and harvest SCM plugin[for eclipse 4.3] , but no sucess over it.

I also tried eclipse kepler[4.3] 64 bit version with 64bit version JRE and with Harvest SCM 64 bit. this is also not working.

same is with eclipse kepler[4.3] 32 bit version with 32bit version JRE and with Harvest SCM 64 bit. this is also not working.

Please don't suggest of using old version of eclipse plugin.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you are at r12.5 release of harvest

Harvest Server and Client : r12.5 (64 bit)
Java : version (64 bit)
Eclipse 4.3 : [64 bit]

Few important points to be considered:
1.All harvest scm components on the macchine ,client , java and Eclipse IDE needs to be either 32 bit or 64 bit .
Please do not use a combination which leads to problems.
2.Eclipse 4.3 is certified with r12.5 harvest release.

It seems to be a configurational issue.
After client is installed verify that the all PATH variables of SCM are in the beginning
SCM , ETPKI and RTHOME(pec)
if you need further assistance please reach out to us in harvest sccm communities.
https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-harvest

where visibility is high

OR please raise a ticket with the CA support

Regards,
Balakrishna.